# What is the difference between "raise" and "rise"?

Tags: differences, verbs, confusables, transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

What is the difference between *raise* and *rise*? When and how should I use each one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Raise" when used as a verb is transitive:  it requires that you have a direct object, a noun of some kind that you are applying the verb to.  For example, "I must raise *an objection*"—"an objection" is the object that the subject (I) is using the verb to act upon.

"Rise" on the other hand, is an intransitive verb:  it does not require a direct object; your sentence can be complete without one.  "Please rise" is entirely correct and complete.

Comment: just curious, are they etymologically related?

Answer (score 1):

Another data point:

Americans, if they are good workers, get a *raise* in pay. The British, however, get a *rise*.