# What's the difference between "rise" and "arise"

Tags: meaning, differences

What is the difference between **rise** and **arise**? When and how should I use each one?

Note: [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4117/what-is-the-difference-between-raise-and-rise)

Comment: Erroneously voted to close the post. How can I cancel my vote?

Comment: @Manoochehr You can't. Hopefully the reviewer will see your comment and decline the flag

Comment: Which verb would you use to mean "wake up"? He rose at 6am, or he arose at 6am?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both arise and rise are irregular verbs.

When an **opportunity**, **problem**, or **new state of affairs** arises, it begins to exist. This is the most common meaning of arise.

> He promised to help Rufus if the occasion arose.
>
> A serious problem has arisen.
>
> The feeling of hope arose from the people.

When something rises, it **moves upwards**.

> The sun rises in the morning.
>
> Clouds of birds rose from the tree-tops.

When someone who is sitting rises, they stand up. You can also use rise to say that someone gets out of bed in the morning.

Cambridge Dictionary also lists rise for "to begin to oppose or fight a bad government or ruler":

> The people rose (up) against the oppressor/tyrant/dictator.

Please visit [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/search/british/?q=rise&x=0&y=0) to see other meanings listed for rise which all are connected with moving upward.

See [Here](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/65582-rise-vs-arise.html).

Comment: Which verb would you use to mean "wake up"? He rose at 6am, or he arose at 6am?